# BeautifulSoup File name prompt

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When I try to run the following in python 3.5 I get the weird prompt

"Enter file name:"

I have already installed BeautifulSoup4 I'm not sure what to do.

The url I would like to parse is as follows:
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Liala.html

Code below:

```
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import ssl

    # Ignore SSL certificate errors
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    url = input('Enter - ')
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # Retrieve all of the anchor tags
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        print(tag.get('href', None))
```

Comment: The script runs fine for me. Please post your error.

Comment: Hi Leo! What do you enter at "Enter file name:"? No matter what I put in I always get

  File "C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Documents\Coursera\Py4e\bs2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Documents\Coursera\Py4e\bs4\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Documents\Coursera\Py4e\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
And on and on

Comment: Which editor are you using.? Also At first I suggest you to define the `URL` in your code rather than than taking user input.

Comment: I'm using atom. Even with a url instead of an input I still get asked for a file name. Don't know how to indent code in a comment, here is what I have
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.check_hostname = False
        ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        quote_page = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Liala.html'

        page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        tags = soup('a')
        for tag in tags:
        print(tag.get('href', None))

Comment: seems like something wrong with `atom` because at my end everything is fine. I suggest you to a different platform. I am using vscode. Hope things will okay then.

Comment: Hi Leo, I don't know what was going on, but I just removed all the other python programs in that folder and it runs perfectly. I guess one of them was interfering with it somehow? Anyway, I wanted to thank you for the help, that was very frustrating.

Comment: Good to know it worked for you.